# pyinstaller не видит библиотеку

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь получить ехе файл из файла mysql.py

```
pyinstaller.exe  --onefile mysql.py
```

но при запуске скомпилированного приложения выдает ошибку

```
No module named 'pymysql'
```

как я понимаю, нужно указать путь до библиотеки.
Пробовал делать так

```
pyinstaller.exe .\mysql.py --onefile -p C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\_init_.py
```

Но это не дало результата. Как правильно указать путь к библиотеке?

Comment: Похоже, при сборке эта библиотека не была автоматически добавлена как зависимость. Нужно добавить вручную название библиотеки в параметр `--hidden-import`: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Comment: попробовал скомпилить так ``` pyinstaller.exe .\mysql.py --onefile --hidden-import=pymysql``` но это не сработало

Comment: Такая же ошибка при запуске?

Comment: да ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Comment: Нет ли путаницы в названии модулей https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360720/5909792 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968501/5909792?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался в чем была проблема. На ПК стояло 2 версии питона, до конца не понимаю как это работает но когда я запускал скрипт через `python mysql.py` запускался питон 3.9 а когда запускал pyinstaller, использовался питон 3.2. Я установил библиотеку на оба питона и скомпилировал приложение. Все заработало, всем спасибо!